# My apachectl commands sends me back "Illegal option ExecGCI"

Tags: apache

i just installed apache by source installation, so after i create virtual host my apachectl doesn't restart, start, stop. My webserver is working i can access but these commands sends me back "illegal option ExeCGI"
This is Virtual host code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/htdocs"
ServerName node.iplaygrid.com
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted 
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html): This option is in a module (mod_cgi). Unless that's active, you won't have the directive available. As you built from source, you'd likely also need to build the modules from source, and definitely load them (or rather: it)